# An Operating System Wasn't Found during installation

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-installation

I have an laptop with Windows Vista on it. My mom forcibly shut it down when it was installing a new Operating System.

So now I tried to install Windows on it again but it showed "Missing OS" and when I tried to boot from a bootable pendrive still it showed "Missing OS".

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that you are actually booting from the installation media and not the hard drive. If it's not actually booting from your installation media, your BIOS is trying to boot from the hard drive first, where this is no OS.

It's also possible something is wrong with your installation media and you need to either recreate it with a verified image or use an OEM or Microsoft re-installation disk.

Verify both of these things and you should be able to reinstall with no problems.

Comment: Especially the last one. If you get the same error message when you think you are booting from an USB pen drive as from the HDD then you really should check if you are actually booting from it.  Test it in an other PC to see if the USB pendrive works as expected. Also this can happen again if you shutdown during upgrades. Simply do not do that. (which I understand might be a very hard thing to teach parents).

Comment: @Hennes I moved things around so that's stated first. More likely that it's boot order rather than a corrupt boot disc.

Comment: @Moses I tried to change the boot order.I made like boot up the usb stick first and load the HDD last but it still showed An Operating system wasnt found.So you tell me that make a installation disc(DVD)

Comment: I would create a bootable disc using Microsoft's tools: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool (for Windows 7) or http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install (for Windows 10)

Comment: So I was performing a factory data reset 
there were 4 stages 
when the system was creating a new windows/system my mom came and forcely closed the laptop
the next time I tried to perform another factory data reset thinking that it might help but it didn't.It started to stop continuing the process at start
So I tried to boot it from a bootable usb device containg Windows Xp. But then it started showing"An OS wasnt found"
I still don't know what to do
Do I have to remove the internal HDD or something else?please help
System:-
Windows Vista Home Premium SP1